# MySQL LEFT JOIN SELECT not selecting all the left side records?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I'm getting odd results from a `MySQL SELECT` query involving a `LEFT JOIN`, and I can't understand whether my understanding of `LEFT JOIN` is wrong or whether I'm seeing a genuinely odd behavior.

I have a two tables with a many-to-one relationship: For every record in `table 1` there are 0 or more records in `table 2`. I want to select all the records in table 1 with a column that counts the number of related records in table 2. As I understand it, `LEFT JOIN` should always return all records on the `LEFT` side of the statement.

Here's a test database that exhibits the problem:

```
CREATE DATABASE Test;
USE Test;

CREATE TABLE Dates (
   dateID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   date DATE NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE KEY (dateID)
) TYPE=MyISAM;


CREATE TABLE Slots (
   slotID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   dateID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE KEY (slotID)
) TYPE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO Dates (date) VALUES ('2008-10-12'),('2008-10-13'),('2008-10-14');
INSERT INTO Slots (dateID) VALUES (3);
```

The Dates table has three records, and the Slots 1 - and that record points to the third record in Dates.

If I do the following query..

```
SELECT d.date, count(s.slotID) FROM Dates AS d LEFT JOIN Slots AS s ON s.dateID=d.dateID GROUP BY s.dateID;
```

..I expect to see a table with 3 rows in - two with a count of 0, and one with a count of 1. But what I actually see is this:

```
+------------+-----------------+
| date       | count(s.slotID) |
+------------+-----------------+
| 2008-10-12 |               0 |
| 2008-10-14 |               1 |
+------------+-----------------+
```

The first record with a zero count appears, but the later record with a zero count is ignored.

Am I doing something wrong, or do I just not understand what LEFT JOIN is supposed to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY d.dateID`.  In two of your cases, `s.DateID` is `NULL` (`LEFT JOIN`) and these are combined together.

I think you will also find that this is invalid (ANSI) SQL, because d.date is not part of a `GROUP BY` or the result of an aggregate operation, and should not be able to be `SELECT`ed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to group by d.dateId.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the GROUP BY s.dateID

Answer (score 1):

The dateid for 10-12 and 10-13 are groupd together by you. Since they are 2 null values the count is evaluated to 0

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is valid in MySQL but you could probably void this mistake in the future by using the following syntax instead

```
SELECT date, count(slotID) as slotCount
FROM Dates LEFT OUTER JOIN Slots USING (dateID)
GROUP BY (date)
```

By using the USING clause you don't get two dateID's to keep track of.

Comment: It works in MySQL (just tested it and it gives the same - correct - results as the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

replace GROUP BY s.dateID with d.dateID.